# How to set the variables in the query string

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, xml

I want to set the variables in the query string , like

```
new XAttribute("onclick", "javascript:document.location.href='/Controller/Action

?a=Va&b=Vb&c=Vc';"),
```

here Va, Vb and Vc are the variables. But if i wrote like this then on button click instead of passing Va, Vb and Vc values it passes these as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want the variables from JavaScript and not the serverside.

```
new XAttribute("onclick", "function(){window.location.href='/Controller/Action?a=' + Va + '&b=' + Vb + '&c=' + Vc;};"),
```

If you want it on the serverside, it is simple string concat

```
new XAttribute("onclick", "window.location.href='/Controller/Action?a="+Va+"&b="+Vb+"&c="+Vc+"';"),
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to exit the quotes to reference the variable.

```
new XAttribute("onclick", "javascript:document.location.href='/Controller/Action

?a=" + Va + "&b=" + Vb + "&c=" + Vc+ "';"),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new XAttribute("onclick", "javascript:document.location.href='/Controller/Action?a="+Va+"&b="+Vb+"&c="+Vc+"';"),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new XAttribute("onclick", string.Format("javascript:document.location.href='/Controller/Action 

?a={0}&b={1}&c={2}';", Va, Vb, Vc));
```